# Woocommerce subscription hook argument only passing user id

Tags: php, woocommerce, subscription, action-hook

I'm tapping into the subscription action hook `scheduled_subscription_payment`.

```
function subscription_renewal($arg) {
    echo, '<pre>' print_r($arg, true);
}
add_action( 'scheduled_subscription_payment', 'subscription_renewal' );
```

Its only returning the user id of the subscriber and I've also tried multiple arguments. I want all the order (subscription) information but cannot find another method to do so. Does this method pass anything but the user id or is there another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This action does pass in two parameters, user_id and the subscription_key. You need to specify that the function takes two arguments, and you need to also specify that your action processes two arguments:

```
// Indicate two parameters in function definition
function subscription_renewal($user_id, $subscription_key) {
  //Logic goes here
}

// Indicate that the action has priority 10 and takes two parameters
add_action( 'scheduled_subscription_payment', 'subscription_renewal', 10, 2 );
```